# Sitecore: prefetch data for custom database

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, config, prefetch

I use additional database in Sitecore solution, let's call it "webextra" database . I need to prefetch data from "webextra" database on site starting, so I use the same "prefetch" config section as for "web" database. But it does not work for "webextra" (data from "web" are fetched as expected). Prefetching runs when I do first call to "webextra" only and it takes a lot of time.
How can I configure to prefetch data when I start the site?

```html
<database id="webextra" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<param desc="name" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">$(id)</param>
<icon>Images/control_image16x16.png</icon>
<securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
<dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
<prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<childLimit>100</childLimit>
<logStats>false</logStats>
<template desc="template">{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}</template>
<template desc="template section">{E269FBB5-3750-427A-9149-7AA950B49301}</template>
<template desc="template field">{455A3E98-A627-4B40-8035-E683A0331AC7}</template>
<template desc="node">{239F9CF4-E5A0-44E0-B342-0F32CD4C6D8B}</template>
<template desc="folder">{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}</template>
<template desc="language">{F68F13A6-3395-426A-B9A1-FA2DC60D94EB}</template>
<template desc="device">{B6F7EEB4-E8D7-476F-8936-5ACE6A76F20B}</template>
<item desc="root">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</item>
<children desc="main sections">{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}</children>
<cacheSize>50MB</cacheSize>
<template desc="alias">{54BCFFB7-8F46-4948-AE74-DA5B6B5AFA86}</template>
<template desc="layout">{3A45A723-64EE-4919-9D41-02FD40FD1466}</template>
<template desc="xsl rendering">{F1F1D639-4F54-40C2-8BE0-81266B392CEB}</template>
<item desc="home">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</item>
<children desc="main items">{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}</children>
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config"/>
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config"/>
</prefetch>
</dataProvider>
</dataProviders>
<proxiesEnabled>false</proxiesEnabled>
<proxyDataProvider ref="proxyDataProviders/main" param1="$(id)" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config"/>
<archives hint="raw:AddArchive" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<archive name="archive" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config"/>
<archive name="recyclebin" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config"/>
</archives>
<cacheSizes hint="setting" patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<data>100MB</data>
<items>50MB</items>
<paths>2500KB</paths>
<itempaths>50MB</itempaths>
<standardValues>2500KB</standardValues>
</cacheSizes>
<Engines.DataEngine.Commands.AddFromTemplatePrototype patch:source="zzz.x.Common.config">
<obj type="Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand, Sitecore.Buckets"/>
</Engines.DataEngine.Commands.AddFromTemplatePrototype>
</database>
```

Comment: In the database section in `Sitecore.config` or `web.config` depending on the Sitecore version, did you add your prefetch path to the `webextra` database?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes, I copied settings from "web" database.

Comment: Can you please share the webextra database section and the prefetch you used

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have updated the question with database section. You can see that I use default prefetch configs: Common.config , Webdb.config

Comment: Instead of using the webdb again, can you create a new one and named it `Webextra.config` and then paste the content from Webdb.config in it. Then, link the new created file by replacing `<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webextra.config" />` to `<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config" />`. Also, go to the cache.aspx page and see if there is an entry for the prefetch cache. Example: `SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data(webextra)`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya it still does not work with Webextra.config file.